# Do I need a primary key with an Oracle identity column?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am using Oracle 12c and I have an `IDENTITY` column set as `GENERATED ALWAYS`.

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
   id            NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   customerName  VARCHAR2(30) NULL,

   CONSTRAINT "CUSTOMER_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);
```

Since the ID is automatically from a sequence it will be always unique.

Do I need a PK on the ID column, and if yes, will it impact the performance?
Would an index produce the same result with a better performance on `INSERT`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need a *primary key* necessarily, but you *should* always provide the optimiser as much information about your data as possible - including a unique constraint whenever possible.

In the case of a surrogate key (like your `ID`), it's almost always appropriate to declare it as a Primary Key, since it's the most likely candidate for referential constraints.

You *could* use an ordinary index on `ID`, and performance of lookups will be comparable depending on data volume - but there is virtually no good reason in this case to use a non-unique index instead of a unique index - and there is no good reason in this case to avoid the constraint which will require an index anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you always should have a Uniqueness constraint (with rare exceptions) on an ID column if indeed it is (and should be) unique, regardless of the method by which it is populated - whether the value is provided by your application code or via an `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: Actually, you can't insert into a `GENERATED ALWAYS IDENTITY` column. Your points about the uniqueness constraint are correct, however.

Comment: @jefry you didn't get my point. Mean to say that the pk column need not be identity and  u can insert the key value urself

Comment: No problem, I've edited it to make your meaning clearer.